# How to check if JRadioButtons are selected?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, nullpointerexception, jradiobutton

I tried

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected() ||(jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
      jGenderGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
} else {
    jGndrErrorLabel.setText("Select gender.")
}
```

But controller doesn't stop after highlighted line it does go ahead to final line and throw `NullPointerException`

```
customers.setGender(jGenderGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand());
```

Where customers is POJO class.

How I can get rid of this?

Comment: But what is `jGenderGroup`?

Comment: It's button group.

Comment: simply check jRadioButton1.isSelected()

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, **select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed `ButtonGroup jGenderGroup`
and perform conditions for `jRadioButton1` and `jRadioButton2` at last instead of middle and as I had commented I can not set `String gender = new String();` as
`gender = jRadioButton1.getActionCommand();`
Within conditional block because of `POJO`
So I just tricked that put it at the end like this :

```
String gender = new String();
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
            gender = jRadioButton1.getActionCommand();
        } else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
            gender = jRadioButton2.getActionCommand();
        } else {
            jGndrErrorLabel.setText("Select gender.");
            jGndrErrorLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
```

That's what I expected
Thanks for all of your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

try this :)

```
jRadioButton1.setActionCommand("Male");  
jRadioButton2.setActionCommand("Female");
if(!jGenderGroup.isChecked()){
jLable1.setText("Please Select Gender");
}
```

Comment: Thre's no such method like `isChecked()` for ButtonGroup.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected())
{
  //Male
}
else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected())
{
  //Female
}
else
{
  // no radio button has been selected
}
```

or alter your code like

```
if(jGenderGroup.getSelection() != null)
 {      
     customer.setGender(jGenderGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand())
} else {
    jGndrErrorLabel.setText("Select gender.")
}
```

Comment: your way also correct and if there are lot of radio buttons in the group that is the way recommended. jGenderButtonGroup.getSelection() returns the ButtonModel of the selected radio button. so no one is selected , it will return null. first check for null, if it is not null then , check for the action command to detect the which radio button has been selected.

Comment: have you added the two buttons to the button group?

Comment: that should throw a null pointer exception, if nothing is selected jGenderButtonGroup.getSelection() is null, see my altered solution